# Windows 7 Processes starting as Suspended

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

All of a sudden, process that I start from the windows desktop are starting as suspended.  For example, I have my Outlook pinned to the start bar.  When I click on it the first time, The mouse cursor goes to busy for a few seconds and then returns to normal.  If I put the cursor over the start bar, it does switch to active (semi-busy?).

However, Outlook never presents itself.  Starting up task manager and then going to the processes tab of the resource monitor shows the outlook process as suspended.  I can right click on the process and Resume it and then everythings seems ok.  However, if I close and restart Outlook the same thing happens again.  Also, if I select other programs from my start menu, they also go into suspended.

Interestingly, IE8, which is also pinned to my start bar, does seem to work normally.

Any help on what is going on would be appreciated.

NOTE: This problem did present itself after a reboot. That actually is what prompted me to post the question. Since then, the problem does seem to have disappeared. And like often happens with these type of problems, I'm not quite sure what I did to resolve it.

Comment: Is this presenting the same behaviour after a clean boot?

Comment: It did.  I added that to the body.

Comment: I am seeing this issue now.  If anyone could breathe new life into this with a fresh answer, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have very similar case, plus some finding, but cannot posted here due to rep limit. For now I posted here: https://superuser.com/a/1636040/1099925

Answer (score 1):

I support many machines on different OS'es and I have never seen this!

First thing I would do is run a virus scanner as this sounds like very suspicious behaviour.

On the other hand, check all anti malware / protection programs you have in case this is some sort of weird protection that has gone wrong.

Comment: It is indeed a very, very strange problem.