# Programs are suspended on startup and ending them causes Explorer to Crash

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

When I start a program(clicking on the icon in the desktop or start menu) my computer brings up the spinning circle tool-tip and then does nothing, as in the computer still works but the program never starts.

If I used a desktop shortcut my Desktop is frozen. Having a program fail like this after opening it from either the Start Menu or the Desktop will cause Explorer to crash when I interact with the Taskbar or Desktop.

Once Explorer has crashed and restarted it gets worse because many of the links on the right side of the Windows 7 Start Menu error out with the message "Remote Procedure Call failed and did not execute." Resource Monitor shows the failed programs I've started as 'Suspended.'

Oddly enough when Google Chrome is one of the programs affected I discovered I can make Chrome start by using the "Search Online" option from the task's context menu in Resource Monitor, but no existing icon will work.

I'm making a new question because the only relevant Google result is [Windows 7 Processes starting as Suspended](https://superuser.com/questions/41123/windows-7-processes-starting-as-suspended), which someone blocked to lurks like me from contributing to, oh and it's two years old with no answer.

Comment: Oh joy, just found out that after explorer has crashed everything on my Desktop also throws RPC error windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had very same case with [Windows 7 Processes starting as Suspended](https://superuser.com/questions/41123/windows-7-processes-starting-as-suspended) I would share my finding here. (I cannot post an answer to above question due to rep requirement)

#### My case was from certain DRM protection service

I found my case when I run **DLsiteViewer** the DRM protected application with **Cypherguard** service. It will run itself in high privilege level, its main purpose is to block every screen capturing action so their protected content cannot be captured. But somehow it is also has this side effect of blocking other process to start.

In the screenshot below, (using Sysinternals process explorer) You can see the troublesome service in purple line.

- I tried to start 4 programs, calc, chrome, HxD, Word, all will exhibits same behavior. A brief busy cursor, then no program will come up.
- And you can see that they are indeed suspended (most likely by Cypherguard)
- You can still start them manually one by one by right click them and "resume" in process explorer.
- This blocking effect goes away if I closed the troublesome application. Future programs can start again without problem.
- But the previously suspended program will not started, they will still there.
- (trivial) I had to use my phone to capture this image as Cypherguard blocks all image
  capturing!
  [image]

#### Your case might be differ

But could come from certain service or application that hook and interfere system operation like mine. The [original post](https://superuser.com/questions/41123/windows-7-processes-starting-as-suspended) reported that restarting machine worked because it clear the troublesome application.

Answer (score 0):

First I would run a [chkdsk /f](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/) on the hard drive.

Then run the [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

Reboot when SFC is finished.

Comment: No fix. The System file Checker did find some bad files, but I really hope the Chinese Language Packs aren't the reason for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience (and a temporary fix), just restart the explorer.exe process.

This caused all other apps to open like normal again for me. This isn't a permanent solution, and I only stumbled upon this when I tried to run cmd as an administrator and my explorer.exe became non-responsive.